# Best practice for setting up wsgi on root directory?

Tags: apache2, mod-wsgi

what's the best ways to mix static files and wsgi app served on the root directory?

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide

recommends setting up

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi
```

and alias other directories and files:

```
Alias /robots.txt /usr/local/www/documents/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /usr/local/www/documents/favicon.ico

Alias /media/ /usr/local/www/documents/media/
```

is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Explain properly what problem you are trying to solve? That is the simplest way of doing things but there are other ways of doing things, some allowing other abilities. Without knowing why this doesn't work for you, can't tell you what to do differently. Also make sure you read 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines', which explains some of the other ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. You need the `Alias` directives to override the `WSGIScriptAlias` directive when handling static media.